# how to add image path in mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql

I am very new to PHP and I need your help.

This is insert.php file that inserts all records.`` File browsing field is also added here. This field browse photo. Temp_File is stored in thumbnails folder. My Question is how to save the image path in MySQL database and how to retrieve this image from dB for displaying in view.php.

//This is insert.php

```
 {<?php require_once('Connections/db_sms.php'); ?>
    <?php
    if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
      session_start();
    }
    $MM_authorizedUsers = "";
    $MM_donotCheckaccess = "true";

    // *** Restrict Access To Page: Grant or deny access to this page
    function isAuthorized($strUsers, $strGroups, $UserName, $UserGroup) { 
      // For security, start by assuming the visitor is NOT authorized. 
      $isValid = False; 

      // When a visitor has logged into this site, the Session variable MM_Username set equal to their username. 
      // Therefore, we know that a user is NOT logged in if that Session variable is blank. 
      if (!empty($UserName)) { 
        // Besides being logged in, you may restrict access to only certain users based on an ID established when they login. 
        // Parse the strings into arrays. 
        $arrUsers = Explode(",", $strUsers); 
        $arrGroups = Explode(",", $strGroups); 
        if (in_array($UserName, $arrUsers)) { 
          $isValid = true; 
        } 
        // Or, you may restrict access to only certain users based on their username. 
        if (in_array($UserGroup, $arrGroups)) { 
          $isValid = true; 
        } 
        if (($strUsers == "") && true) { 
          $isValid = true; 
        } 
      } 
      return $isValid; 
    }

    $MM_restrictGoTo = "login.php";
    if (!((isset($_SESSION['MM_Username'])) && (isAuthorized("",$MM_authorizedUsers, $_SESSION['MM_Username'], $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'])))) {   
      $MM_qsChar = "?";
      $MM_referrer = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
      if (strpos($MM_restrictGoTo, "?")) $MM_qsChar = "&";
      if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) && strlen($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) > 0) 
      $MM_referrer .= "?" . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
      $MM_restrictGoTo = $MM_restrictGoTo. $MM_qsChar . "accesscheck=" . urlencode($MM_referrer);
      header("Location: ". $MM_restrictGoTo); 
      exit;
    }
    ?>
    <?php
    if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
    function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
    {
      if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
        $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
      }

      $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

      switch ($theType) {
        case "text":
          $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
          break;    
        case "long":
        case "int":
          $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
          break;
        case "double":
          $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
          break;
        case "date":
          $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
          break;
        case "defined":
          $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
          break;
      }
      return $theValue;
    }
    }

    $editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
      $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
    }

    if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "regform")) {
      $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO tbl_student (s_id, first_name, last_name, gender, dob, father_name, email, address, city) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                           GetSQLValueString($_POST['student_photo'], "text"),
                           GetSQLValueString($_POST['first_name'], "text"),
                           GetSQLValueString($_POST['last_name'], "text"),
                           GetSQLValueString($_POST['gender'], "text"),
                           GetSQLValueString($_POST['dob'], "date"),
                           GetSQLValueString($_POST['father_name'], "text"),
                           GetSQLValueString($_POST['email'], "text"),
                           GetSQLValueString($_POST['address'], "text"),
                           GetSQLValueString($_POST['city'], "text"));

      mysql_select_db($database_db_sms, $db_sms);
      $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $db_sms) or die(mysql_error());

      $insertGoTo = "view.php";
      if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
        $insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
        $insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
      }
      header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
    }
    ?>
    <?php require_once('Zend/Date.php'); ?>
    <?php $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $host = "localhost";
    $database = "db_sms";

    // Make the connect to MySQL or die
    // and display an error.
    $link = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
    if (!$link) {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    // Select your database
    mysql_select_db ($database);?>


    <?php if (isset($_FILES['student_photo']) && $_FILES['student_photo']['size'] > 0) { 

              // Temporary file name stored on the server
              $tmpName  = $_FILES['student_photo']['tmp_name'];  
              // Create the query and insert
              // into our database.
              $i=rand(0,8888);
               $info=pathinfo($_FILES['student_photo']['name']);
                $ext=$info['extension'];
                $i++;
                $newname="pic_".$i.".".$ext;
                $target='thumbnails/'.$newname;
              move_uploaded_file($_FILES['student_photo']['tmp_name'], $target );
              $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_students ";
              $query .= "(student_photo) VALUES ('$data')";
              $results = mysql_query($query, $link);

              // Print results
              print "Thank you, your file has been uploaded.";

    }
    else {
       print "No image selected/uploaded";
    }


    mysql_close($link);
    ?>


    <?php
    if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
    function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 




      if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
        $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
      }

      $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

      switch ($theType) {
        case "text":
          $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
          break;    
        case "long":
        case "int":
          $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
          break;
        case "double":
          $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
          break;
        case "date":
           if ($theValue == "")
          {
              $theValue = "NULL";
          }
          else
          {
              $zendDate = new Zend_Date($theValue, "d/M/yyyy");
              $theValue = "'" . $zendDate->toString("dd-MM-yyyy") . "'";
          }
          break;
        case "defined":
          $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
          break;
      }
      return $theValue;
    }
    }

    mysql_select_db($database_db_sms, $db_sms);
    $query_rsStudent = "SELECT s_id, first_name, last_name, gender, dob, father_name, email, address, city, student_photo FROM tbl_student ORDER BY first_name ASC";
    $rsStudent = mysql_query($query_rsStudent, $db_sms) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_rsStudent = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsStudent);
    $totalRows_rsStudent = mysql_num_rows($rsStudent);

    $query_rsStudent = "SELECT first_name, last_name, gender, dob, father_name, email, address, city FROM tbl_student ORDER BY first_name ASC";
    $rsStudent = mysql_query($query_rsStudent, $db_sms) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_rsStudent = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsStudent);
    $totalRows_rsStudent = mysql_num_rows($rsStudent);
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Registration</title>

    <script src="SpryAssets/SpryValidationTextField.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="SpryAssets/SpryValidationRadio.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="SpryAssets/SpryValidationTextField.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="SpryAssets/SpryValidationRadio.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <style type="text/css">
    body,td,th {
        font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
        font-size: 18px;
        color: #FFFFFF;
    }
    body {
        background-color: #636;
        margin-left: 400px;
        margin-top: 100px;
        margin-right: 400px;
    }
    </style>
    </head>

    <body>
    <?php /* include('include/header.php');*/ ?>
    <form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" name="regform" id="regform" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">

    <table width="1495" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td width="115">First Name</td>
        <td width="1370"><span id="spryfirstname">
        <input name="first_name" type="text"    maxlength="50" />
        <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span><span class="textfieldMaxCharsMsg">Exceeded maximum number of characters.</span></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Last Name</td>
        <td><span id="sprylastname">
        <input name="last_name" type="text"    maxlength="50" />
        <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span><span class="textfieldMaxCharsMsg">Exceeded maximum number of characters.</span></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Gender</td>
        <td><label>
        <span id="spryrggender">
        <input  type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" id="male" />
    Male<br />
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" id="female" />
    Female<br />
    <span class="radioRequiredMsg">Required.</span></span></label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Date Of Birth</td>
        <td><span id="sprydob">
        <input name="dob" type="text"   />
        <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">Date of Birth is required.</span><span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Invalid format.</span></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Father's Name</td>
        <td><span id="spryfathername">
        <input name="father_name" type="text"  maxlength="50" />
        <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span><span class="textfieldMaxCharsMsg">Exceeded maximum number of characters.</span></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>E-mail Address</td>
        <td><span id="spryemail">
        <input name="email" type="text"   />
        <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span><span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Invalid format.</span><span class="textfieldMaxCharsMsg">Exceeded maximum number of characters.</span></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Address</td>
        <td><span id="spryaddress">
        <input name="address" type="text"  />
        <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span><span class="textfieldMaxCharsMsg">Exceeded maximum number of characters.</span></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>City</td>
        <td><span id="sprycity">
          <input name="city" type="text"  />
          <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span><span class="textfieldMaxCharsMsg">Exceeded maximum number of characters.</span></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Upload image</td>
        <td>
          <input type="file" name="student_photo" id="student_photo" />
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><input name="insert" type="submit" value="Insert Record" /></td>
      </tr>

    </table>
    <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="regform" />
    </form>

    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var sprytextfield1 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("spryfirstname", "none", {validateOn:["blur"], maxChars:50});
    var sprytextfield2 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprylastname", "none", {validateOn:["blur"], maxChars:50});
    var spryradio1 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationRadio("spryrggender", {validateOn:["blur"]});
    var sprytextfield3 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprydob", "date", {format:"dd/mm/yyyy", validateOn:["blur"], hint:"dd/mm/yyyy"});
    var sprytextfield4 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("spryfathername", "none", {validateOn:["blur"], maxChars:50});
    var sprytextfield5 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("spryemail", "email", {maxChars:50, validateOn:["blur"]});
    var sprytextfield6 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("spryaddress", "none", {maxChars:50, validateOn:["blur"]});
    var sprytextfield7 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprycity", "none", {maxChars:50, validateOn:["blur"]});
    var sprytextfield8 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield8");
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
    <?php
    mysql_free_result($rsStudent);
    ?>

////////
This is view.php file in which record is displayed
----


<?php require_once('Connections/db_sms.php'); ?>
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}
$MM_authorizedUsers = "";
$MM_donotCheckaccess = "true";

// *** Restrict Access To Page: Grant or deny access to this page
function isAuthorized($strUsers, $strGroups, $UserName, $UserGroup) { 
  // For security, start by assuming the visitor is NOT authorized. 
  $isValid = False; 

  // When a visitor has logged into this site, the Session variable MM_Username set equal to their username. 
  // Therefore, we know that a user is NOT logged in if that Session variable is blank. 
  if (!empty($UserName)) { 
    // Besides being logged in, you may restrict access to only certain users based on an ID established when they login. 
    // Parse the strings into arrays. 
    $arrUsers = Explode(",", $strUsers); 
    $arrGroups = Explode(",", $strGroups); 
    if (in_array($UserName, $arrUsers)) { 
      $isValid = true; 
    } 
    // Or, you may restrict access to only certain users based on their username. 
    if (in_array($UserGroup, $arrGroups)) { 
      $isValid = true; 
    } 
    if (($strUsers == "") && true) { 
      $isValid = true; 
    } 
  } 
  return $isValid; 
}

$MM_restrictGoTo = "login.php";
if (!((isset($_SESSION['MM_Username'])) && (isAuthorized("",$MM_authorizedUsers, $_SESSION['MM_Username'], $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'])))) {   
  $MM_qsChar = "?";
  $MM_referrer = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
  if (strpos($MM_restrictGoTo, "?")) $MM_qsChar = "&";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) && strlen($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) > 0) 
  $MM_referrer .= "?" . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  $MM_restrictGoTo = $MM_restrictGoTo. $MM_qsChar . "accesscheck=" . urlencode($MM_referrer);
  header("Location: ". $MM_restrictGoTo); 
  exit;
}
?>
<?php require_once('Zend/Date.php');?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

$currentPage = $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];



$maxRows_rsStudent = 3;
$pageNum_rsStudent = 0;
if (isset($_GET['pageNum_rsStudent'])) {
  $pageNum_rsStudent = $_GET['pageNum_rsStudent'];
}
$startRow_rsStudent = $pageNum_rsStudent * $maxRows_rsStudent;

mysql_select_db($database_db_sms, $db_sms);
$query_rsStudent = "SELECT s_id, first_name, last_name, gender, dob, father_name, email, address, city, student_photo FROM tbl_student ORDER BY first_name ASC";
$query_limit_rsStudent = sprintf("%s LIMIT %d, %d", $query_rsStudent, $startRow_rsStudent, $maxRows_rsStudent);
$rsStudent = mysql_query($query_limit_rsStudent, $db_sms) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rsStudent = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsStudent);

if (isset($_GET['totalRows_rsStudent'])) {
  $totalRows_rsStudent = $_GET['totalRows_rsStudent'];
} else {
  $all_rsStudent = mysql_query($query_rsStudent);
  $totalRows_rsStudent = mysql_num_rows($all_rsStudent);
}
$totalPages_rsStudent = ceil($totalRows_rsStudent/$maxRows_rsStudent)-1;

$queryString_rsStudent = "";
if (!empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $params = explode("&", $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
  $newParams = array();
  foreach ($params as $param) {
    if (stristr($param, "pageNum_rsStudent") == false && 
        stristr($param, "totalRows_rsStudent") == false) {
      array_push($newParams, $param);
    }
  }
  if (count($newParams) != 0) {
    $queryString_rsStudent = "&" . htmlentities(implode("&", $newParams));
  }
}
$queryString_rsStudent = sprintf("&totalRows_rsStudent=%d%s", $totalRows_rsStudent, $queryString_rsStudent);
?>

<?php


if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
       if ($theValue == "")
      {
          $theValue = "NULL";
      }
      else
      {
          $zendDate = new Zend_Date($theValue, "M/d/yyyy");
          $theValue = "'" . $zendDate->toString("yyyy-MM-dd") . "'";
      }
        break;

    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}
?>
<style type="text/css">
body,td,th {
    color: #000;
    font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 18px;
}
body {
    background-color: #FFF;
}
a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #606;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #066;
}
a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #600;
}
</style>

<body bgcolor="#D6D6D6" text="#FFFFFF" link="#330000" vlink="#006666" alink="#660000"><h1>
  <style type="text/css">
#header {
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    color: #066;
    background-color: #FFF;
    background-image: url(../images/contest.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: auto;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    margin-bottom: 400px;
}
body,td,th {
    font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
    color: #000;
}
body {
    background-color: #FFF;
}
  </style>
</h1>
 <?php /* include('include/header.php');*/?> 

<h3>&nbsp;</h3>
<h3>There are <?php echo $totalRows_rsStudent ?> Students.</h3>
<p>&nbsp;
  <?php if ($pageNum_rsStudent > 0) { // Show if not first page ?>
    <a href="<?php printf("%s?pageNum_rsStudent=%d%s", $currentPage, 0, $queryString_rsStudent); ?>">First</a> <a href="<?php printf("%s?pageNum_rsStudent=%d%s", $currentPage, max(0, $pageNum_rsStudent - 1), $queryString_rsStudent); ?>">Previous</a>
    <?php } // Show if not first page ?>
  <?php if ($pageNum_rsStudent < $totalPages_rsStudent) { // Show if not last page ?>
  <a href="<?php printf("%s?pageNum_rsStudent=%d%s", $currentPage, min($totalPages_rsStudent, $pageNum_rsStudent + 1), $queryString_rsStudent); ?>">Next</a> <a href="<?php printf("%s?pageNum_rsStudent=%d%s", $currentPage, $totalPages_rsStudent, $queryString_rsStudent); ?>">Last</a>
  <?php } // Show if not last page ?>
</p>
<table width="400" border="0">

</table>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table width="2139" border="0">

    <tr>
      <th width="326" bgcolor="#009999" scope="col"><strong>First Name</strong></th>
      <th width="315" bgcolor="#009999" scope="col"><strong>Last Name</strong></th>
      <th width="282" bgcolor="#009999" scope="col"><strong>Gender</strong></th>
      <th width="183" bgcolor="#009999" scope="col"><blockquote>
        <p> <strong>BirthDate</strong></p>
      </blockquote></th>
      <th width="337" bgcolor="#009999" scope="col"><strong>Father's Name</strong></th>
      <th width="271" bgcolor="#009999" scope="col"><strong>Email</strong></th>
      <th width="95" bgcolor="#009999" scope="col"><strong>Address</strong></th>
      <th width="150" bgcolor="#009999" scope="col"><strong>City</strong></th>
      <th width="150" bgcolor="#009999" scope="col"><blockquote>
        <p>Photo</p>
      </blockquote></th>
      <th width="150" bgcolor="#009999" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
      <th width="7" bgcolor="#009999" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
      <th width="131" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
     <?php do { ?>
   <?php 
            $zendDate = new Zend_Date($row_rsStudent['dob']);
          ?>

    <tr>
      <td bgcolor="#333333"><blockquote>
        <p><a href="update.php?s_id=<?php echo $row_rsStudent['s_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row_rsStudent['first_name']; ?></a></p>
      </blockquote></td>
      <td bgcolor="#333333"><blockquote>
        <p><?php echo $row_rsStudent['last_name']; ?></p>
      </blockquote></td>
      <td bgcolor="#333333"><blockquote>
        <p><?php echo $row_rsStudent['gender']; ?></p>
      </blockquote></td>
      <td bgcolor="#333333"> 
          <?php echo $zendDate->toString("d/M/yyyy"); ?></td>
      <td bgcolor="#333333"><blockquote>
        <p><?php echo $row_rsStudent['father_name']; ?></p>
      </blockquote></td>
      <td bgcolor="#333333"><blockquote>
        <p><?php echo $row_rsStudent['email']; ?></p>
      </blockquote></td>



      <td bgcolor="#333333"><blockquote>
        <p><em><strong><a href="delete.php?s_id=<?php echo $row_rsStudent['s_id']; ?>"></a></strong></em><?php echo $row_rsStudent['address']; ?></p>
      </blockquote></td>
      <td bgcolor="#333333"><blockquote>
        <p><em><strong><a href="delete.php?s_id=<?php echo $row_rsStudent['s_id']; ?>"></a></strong></em><?php echo $row_rsStudent['city']; ?></p>
      </blockquote></td>
      <td bgcolor="#333333"><blockquote>
        <p><img src="<?php echo "thumbnails/".$row_rsStudent['student_photo']; ?>"/> </p>
      </blockquote></td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><blockquote>
        <p><em><strong><a href="delete.php?s_id=<?php echo $row_rsStudent['s_id']; ?>">Delete</a></strong></em></p>
      </blockquote></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } while ($row_rsStudent = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsStudent)); ?>
  </table>
  <p><strong><a href="insert.php">Insert New Record</a></strong></p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
</form>
<?php
mysql_free_result($rsStudent);
?>
```

/////
This is my db_sms connectiion file

```
<?php
# FileName="Connection_php_mysql.htm"
# Type="MYSQL"
# HTTP="true"
$hostname_db_sms = "localhost";
$database_db_sms = "db_sms";
$username_db_sms = "root";
$password_db_sms = "";
$db_sms = mysql_pconnect($hostname_db_sms, $username_db_sms, $password_db_sms) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 
?>
```

//////
This is mysql database file db_dms.sql

--

```
phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 3.2.0.1
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Dec 06, 2012 at 05:07 AM
-- Server version: 5.1.36
-- PHP Version: 5.3.0

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";

--
-- Database: `db_sms`
--
CREATE DATABASE `db_sms` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
USE `db_sms`;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `tbl_admin`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_admin` (
  `admin_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`admin_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `tbl_admin`
--

INSERT INTO `tbl_admin` (`admin_id`, `username`, `password`) VALUES
(1, 'root', 'root');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `tbl_student`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_student` (
  `s_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `dob` date NOT NULL,
  `father_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `student_photo` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`s_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=18 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `tbl_student`
--

INSERT INTO `tbl_student` (`s_id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `gender`, `dob`, `father_name`, `email`, `address`, `city`, `student_photo`) VALUES
(3, 'Zara', 'Mansoor', 'Female', '0000-00-00', 'mmmm', 'zara@xyz.com', 'dddd', 'dddd', 'pic_1074.jpg'),
```

Comment: In the future, try to narrow down what you think is the problematic area of the code and post only what's needed to illustrate the problem. That's quite a bit of code to read :)

Answer (score 1):

just save name of image(include folder path if required) in column of table with varchar data type. And retrieve that image name from db and place it in image tag. Eg

```
<img src="<?php echo $image_path?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I do this is to save either the relative or relative to `DocumentRoot` path into the database as varchar (512). This seems to work for me nicely. I think you can actually save an image as [glob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17751865/store-image-in-mysql-blob) into the database, but I don't think that is what you want.

The records might look like this, with field name `item_image_uri` in table `item_image_table`:

```
"images/image1.png"
"images/image2.png"
```

Then, your database call would be something like this:

```
SELECT item_image_uri FROM item_image_table;
```

You can then loop through the results with PHP or specify exact images.